# How to convert a ggplot2 functions to simple XY equation

Tags: r, ggplot2

I just wanna to do these functions lm ns without of ggplot2. How can I code this to a simple XY function or other way out of ggplot2

```
stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ ns(x,2), size = 1.5, se=T)
```

Comment: See the example [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/splines/versions/3.5.1/topics/ns).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the function to a formula and plot it using plotly as below:

```
set.seed(2018)
Plt_Input <- data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE)))
names(Plt_Input) <- c("y","x")

fit <- lm(formula = y ~ x, data = Plt_Input)
R2 <- paste ("R2 =", round(summary(fit)$r.squared,2))
Formula <- paste('y =', round(coef(fit)[[1]],1), ' + (', round(fit$coefficients[[2]],2),'*x )' )


Plt_Input %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~x, showlegend = FALSE) %>% 
  add_markers(y = ~y, opacity = 0.7, color = 'rgb(0, 150, 100)') %>% 
  add_lines(x = ~x, y = fitted(fit))%>% 
  layout(title="a",
         annotations = list(x = 60, y = 42, showarrow = TRUE, arrowhead = 2,arrowsize = 0.5,ax = 90, ay = -60,
                            text = paste (Formula, R2, sep='\n'),
                            font = list(family = "Cambria, monospace", fontface = "bold", color = "black", size = 14)))
```